# Prove that a function similar to the popcorn function is continuous at $1$

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm trying to prove that
$$f: f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1/q & x = p/q \,\, \text{in lowest terms} \\
      1 & x \notin \mathbb{Q}
   \end{cases}$$
is continuous at $1$.

I've come to terms with the proof that the similar function
$$g: g(x) = \begin{cases} 
      1/q & x = p/q \,\, \text{in lowest terms} \\
      0 & x \notin \mathbb{Q}
   \end{cases}$$
is such that $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$ for all $a$. However I can't find an argument that works for $f$.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false: the function $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$. Consider the sequence
$$
a_n=\frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{n}.
$$
Clearly $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=1$ but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0\neq f(1)
$$
where we used the fact that gcd$(n,n+1)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

From the negation of the definition of continuity:

$\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall \delta>0$, there is a $x$ such that $|x-1|$ $<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(1)|$$\geq\epsilon$.

Take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$

Choose $x=\frac{p}{q},\forall q>2$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1$. $\forall \delta>0$, we can find $p,q$ such that $|x-1|<\delta$.

Now,

$|f(x)-f(1)|=|\frac{1}{q}-1|=|\frac{1}{2+j}-1|$ for some $j\in Z^{+}$

$|f(x)-f(1)|=|\frac{1}{2+j}-1|=|1-\frac{1}{2+j}|$$\geq$$|1-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$$=\epsilon$

Thus, $|f(x)-f(1)|$$\geq$$\epsilon$
.So, the function is not continuous at $x=1$.